# No space left on .3075? What does that mean?

Tags: fedora

In [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310739/installing-mathematics-10-4-on-fedora-extraction-failed-no-space-left-on-3286) which wasn't answered, I posted my problem. After all this time, I have removed fedora, and then installed it on a 150 GB partition. Although the first thing I did after installing Fedora is install Mathematica, it failed, with the same error:
"Extraction failed. No space left on .3075":

```
[root@waylons-air Downloads]# chmod +x m11.sh
[root@waylons-air Downloads]# sh m11.sh
Mathematica 11.0.1 for LINUX Installer Archive

Verifying archive integrity. 
Extracting installer. .................Extraction failed. No space left on .5729
Removing temporary files.
[root@waylons-air Downloads]# df
Filesystem              1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                  1511900        0   1511900   0% /dev
tmpfs                     1521616     6736   1514880   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     1521616     1372   1520244   1% /run
tmpfs                     1521616        0   1521616   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/fedora-root 151058636 12848032 130514220   9% /
tmpfs                      304324       12    304312   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                      304324       36    304288   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs                    14648488        0  14648488   0% /tmp
[root@waylons-air Downloads]# df -i
Filesystem               Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
devtmpfs                 210476    440  210036    1% /dev
tmpfs                    215334     15  215319    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    215334    710  214624    1% /run
tmpfs                    215334     14  215320    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/fedora-root 9601024 151769 9449255    2% /
tmpfs                    215334     17  215317    1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                    215334     24  215310    1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs                    215334      1  215333    1% /tmp
```

Answer (score 2):

You can move the location of temporary directory that's used for the installation with this command. (It sets `TMPDIR` to your home directory for the duration of running `m11.sh`.)

```
TMPDIR=~ ./m11.sh
```

`m11.sh` uses `/tmp` as default which is a relatively small tmpfs partition on your machine.

```
$ head -n5 Mathematica_11.0.0_LINUX.sh
#!/bin/sh
# This script was generated using Makeself 2.1.1
CRCsum="823848904"
MD5="5f9bd533e1692994eb5c0f503153393a"
TMPROOT=${TMPDIR:=/tmp}
```

Comment: Total beginner here. How do I change the default for my .sh file?

Comment: Look at the first line of my answer.

Comment: Do I use it with export?

Comment: You have to use copypaste or write it yourself, it's only 15 characters.

Comment: [mohd@waylons-air Downloads]$ TMPDIR=~ m11.sh

bash: m11.sh: command not found...

Comment: Sorry. Added 2 more extra chars.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. I even tried umounting and mounting /tmp, and I assigned 5GBs for it, and still the problem persists.

Comment: It requires about 10gb free space.

Comment: I made it about 15gb, and it didn't work. I edited my original post with the new df and df -i outputs

Answer (score -1):

sync command is used to copy all contents from cache to memory. caching does make some processes faster, but swap memory space reduces, causing the "no space left" error to come up.

run the sync command as root user.

```
$ sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
$ sync; echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
$ sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

After running these commands, run the `$ free -g` command to check the free, used and total available memory, cache and swap spaces.